# convergence in probability, question

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution

Let $Y_1, ..., Y_n \sim Unif(0, \theta)$ iid and $M_n = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} Y_i$. I am trying to show, that $M_n \to \theta$ in probability, i.e.

$\forall \epsilon > 0,\mathbb{P} [ |M_n - \theta| > \epsilon ] \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$.

I already have
$\mathbb{P} [ |M_n - \theta| > \epsilon ] = \mathbb{P} [ M_n - \theta > \epsilon ] + \mathbb{P} [ - M_n + \theta > \epsilon ]$

and I can show that the second term tends to zero, but what about

$\mathbb{P} [ M_n - \theta > \epsilon ]$ ?

How can I show that this probability also converges to $0$?

Comment: can the maximum be greater than $\theta$ if the random variables are $U(0,\theta)$?

Comment: No, because of the definition. Thanks.